# how to store the values of edittext in database and then how to get that back

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-widget

I'm trying to put the value from an EditText into a database and then get the value from that database.

I tried to store the values in database when the button is clicked in the activity as follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class hjhj extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private EditText txt,txt1;

    Button b;

    String nam;
    String ag;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        txt1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText02);
        b=(Button) this.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);         
   }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nam=txt.getText().toString();
        ag=txt1.getText().toString();

        new DetailsOpenHelper(this);

    }


}
```

DetailsOpenHelper:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DetailsOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static String DATABASE_NAME="employeedatabase";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DETAILS_TABLE_NAME = "employeedetails";

    private static String nam;
    private static String ag;

    static String NAME=nam;
    static String AGE=ag;
    private String KEY_ROWID;

    private static final String DETAILS_TABLE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + DETAILS_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                NAME + " TEXT, " +
                AGE + " TEXT);";

    private SQLiteOpenHelper mSQL;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;



    public DetailsOpenHelper(hjhj hjhj){
        super(hjhj, DATABASE_NAME, null,DATABASE_VERSION );
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         db.execSQL(DETAILS_TABLE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DETAILS_TABLE_IF_NOT_EXISTS");
        onCreate(db);
    }


      public void open() throws SQLException
        {
          DetailsOpenHelper mSQL = new DetailsOpenHelper(null);
            db = mSQL.getWritableDatabase();
         } 


    private void addDetails( String nam, String ag) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = mSQL.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(NAME, nam);
            //values.put(TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
            values.put(AGE, ag);
            db.insert(DETAILS_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        }

      public Cursor getAllDetails() 
      {
          return db.query(DETAILS_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                  KEY_ROWID, 
                  NAME,
                  AGE  },  null, null, null, null, null, null);
      }   


      public boolean updateDetails(long rowId, String nam, 
              String ag) 
              {
                  ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
                  args.put(NAME, nam);
                  args.put(AGE, ag);

                  return db.update(DETAILS_TABLE_NAME, args, 
                                   KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
              }

}
```

I want to store and retrieve the values when I click the button. Please can anyone help me if you know about this. I have tried a lot.

Also, how do I view the database with the command prompt?

Comment: Is there an error? if yes, what is it?Use LogCat, it will help you identify the cause of the error and to view the database in command prompt you will need sqlite

Answer (score 1):

```
ReminderDbAdopter.java (simply a java class)


package com.studentdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class RemindersDbAdapter {

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) { 
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE); 
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,
        int newVersion) { 
        // Not used, but you could upgrade the database with ALTER
        // Scripts
        }

        }


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studinfo";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "student";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String USERNAME= "title";
    public static final String ROLLNUM = "id";
    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
    + ROLLNUM + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + USERNAME + " text not null);";
    private final Context mCtx;
    public RemindersDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
    }
    public RemindersDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
    }
    public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
    }
    public long createReminder(String title) { 
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(USERNAME, title);
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

    }
    public boolean deleteReminder(long rowId) {
    return
    mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, ROLLNUM + "=" + rowId, null) > 0; 
    }
    public Cursor fetchAllReminders() { 
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {ROLLNUM,USERNAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        public Cursor fetchReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException { 
        Cursor mCursor =
        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {ROLLNUM,
        USERNAME, }, ROLLNUM + "=" +
        rowId, null,
        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
        }
        public boolean updateReminder(long rowId, String title) { 
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(USERNAME, title);
        return
        mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args,ROLLNUM + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }
        // The SQLiteOpenHelper class was omitted for brevity
        // That code goes here.



}


ReminderEditActivity  (main activity)



package com.studentdemo;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ReminderEditActivity extends Activity {
private RemindersDbAdapter mDbHelper;
private EditText mTitleText;
private Button mConfirmButton;
private Long mRowId;
@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mDbHelper = new RemindersDbAdapter(this);
setContentView(R.layout.reminder_edit);
mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
setmConfirmButton((Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm));
mRowId = savedInstanceState != null 
? savedInstanceState.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.ROLLNUM): null;
registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText();
}



private void registerButtonListenersAndSetDefaultText() {
    {
        mConfirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
            saveState(); 
            setResult(RESULT_OK); 
            Toast.makeText(ReminderEditActivity.this,
            getString(R.string.hello),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            }
            });
    }
    }








private void setRowIdFromIntent() {
if (mRowId == null) {
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
mRowId = extras != null
? extras.getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.ROLLNUM)
: null;
}
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
mDbHelper.close(); 
}
@Override
protected void onResume() { 
super.onResume();
mDbHelper.open(); 
setRowIdFromIntent(); 
populateFields(); 
}
// Date picker, button click events, and buttonText updating, createDialog
// left out for brevity
// they normally go here ...
private void populateFields() { 
if (mRowId != null) {
Cursor reminder = mDbHelper.fetchReminder(mRowId); 
startManagingCursor(reminder); 
mTitleText.setText(reminder.getString(
reminder.getColumnIndexOrThrow(RemindersDbAdapter.USERNAME)));
}
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putLong(RemindersDbAdapter.ROLLNUM, mRowId);
}
private void saveState() {
String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
if (mRowId == null) { 
long id = mDbHelper.createReminder(title);
if (id > 0) {
mRowId = id; 
}
} else {
mDbHelper.updateReminder(mRowId, title); 
}
}
public void setmConfirmButton(Button mConfirmButton) {
    this.mConfirmButton = mConfirmButton;
}
public Button getmConfirmButton() {
    return mConfirmButton;
}



}

reminder_edit.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Write student information:"/>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
        android:layout_below="@id/label"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text="save" />

</RelativeLayout>



then run the program
you can find the database 1.click start button in your window
2.choose run 
3.type adb shell(before it you set the path of adb in mycomputer properties C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\platforms)
4.then type
cd data
cd data
cd your packagename
cd databases
sqlite3 studinfo
.tables
you find ur table name
```

Comment: Hey one up vote for that. You have given me what I was looking for. I have successfully inserted the data in the table. Now I want to populate the data present in the table on the textview on onStart() of the activity. Please can you tell me how to do that. That will obviously solve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I did this task in one of my project for remember username & password option.
In this, there is 2 EditView and and ImageButton for remember username an password.
When user click on remember button his username an password are saved in database.
See the code below and try to take help from this:

```
    final ImageButton login=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Login);
    final ImageButton register=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Register);
    final ImageButton remember=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.remember);

this.myDbAdapter=new DBAdapter(this);
List<String> email = this.myDbAdapter.selectAll();

editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailText);
editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
if(!email.isEmpty()){
    remember.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked);
    editText1.setText(email.get(0));
    editText2.setText(email.get(1));
}   

remember.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(Config.rememberLogin==0){
                remember.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checked);
                Config.rememberLogin=1;
                //myDbAdapter.deleteAll();

                myDbAdapter.insert(editText1.getText()+"",editText2.getText()+"");

            }
            else{
                     remember.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.check_none);
                Config.rememberLogin=0;
                myDbAdapter.deleteAll();

            }       
        }
    });
```

where **rememberLogin is public static int  member of Config class** to check whether remember button is used or not.
and here is the function **selectAll() & deleteAll() of myDbAdapter** class :

```
public void deleteAll() 
     {
       this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
      }

     public List<String> selectAll() {
          List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"email","password"}, 
            null, null, null, null,null);
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));
                list.add(cursor.getString(1));
             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          }
          if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
             cursor.close();
          }
          return list;
       }
```

Hope these code will help you...:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, call your Database class with application startup itself and make a connection with it.

As i can see, new DetailsOpenHelper(this) is called from onClick() method, this will open connection everytime you click a button.

in Onclick() method call addDetails() methods and pass on editText value in that.

I Hope this will work in your case.

Comment: if i do like like above means

Comment: if i do like like above means error " ((object).db).adddetails() in onclick

Answer (score 0):

Its very eassy...

just try this code

```
final EditText edit_name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
    final EditText edit_phone_numer=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_phone_number);
    Button add_new=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add_new);
    Button saved_data=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_saved_data);
    Button more_option=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
    final Table tb=new Table(this);

    final String _name=edit_name.getText().toString();
    final String _phone_number=edit_phone_numer.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(_name);
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), _name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println(_phone_number);

    add_new.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            edit_name.setText("");
            edit_phone_numer.setText("");
        }
    });

    saved_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tb.open();
            final String _name=edit_name.getText().toString();
            final String _phone_number=edit_phone_numer.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(_name);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Record Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println(_phone_number);
            tb.createemployee(_name, _phone_number);
            tb.delete("12");
            tb.close();
        }
    });
    more_option.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, moreoption.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I don't know if you already got your answer, but as you didn't marked any as that I'll assume you didn't. If any answer got you in the right direction you should mark it.

Assuming as well your code doesn't contain any errors (I didn't test it).

- To store the values in the database:
  after this code: new DetailsOpenHelper(this); in onClick, call your addDetails function using the nam and ag variables. Just that.
- To retrieve values from the database:
  there is a function (getAllDetails) that will return a cursor exposing every record in the database. U can modify it a little to expose only one record. Let me know if you want to know about that too. Using the function as it is:
  after the modification above:

  Cursor cursor = getAllDetails();
  cursor.moveToFirst();
  nam = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("nam"));
  ag = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ag"));
  txt.setText(nam);
  txt.setText(ag);

This should get your first code running but I recommend you learn to use listView to show results from the cursor.

Best regards